# Trying to track down NoReverseMatch in new app

Tags: django, django-views

So I did one of the many blog tutorials and now I'm working on my own app.  I'm running up against this error:

```
Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'asset_name': u'sfossnse01vmw147'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Here is my models file:

```
from django.db import models


#Basic tracking information of assets:
#Host name
#IP Address
#CNames assigned in eng.silverspringnet.com
#eng cluster
#Description
#Owner

# Create your models here.

class Asset(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
#    modified_date = models.DateTimeField()
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    asset_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    fqdn = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    cluster_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField()

    def create_asset(self):
        self.created_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.asset_name
```

And my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Asset 
from pysphere import VIServer
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

# Create your views here.

# Huge performance penalty here
#def vm_status(vm_name):
#    server = VIServer()
#    server.connect("it-vcenter-01.silverspringnet.com", "jhamm@silverspringnet.com", "St31l@h@mMn1reug")
#    vm = server.get_vm_by_name(vm_name)
#    vm_stat = vm.get_status(vm)
#    server.disconnect()
#    return vm_stat 

def asset_list(request): 

    assets = Asset.objects.all()

#    for vm in assets:
#        vm_stat = vm_status(vm.fqdn)

    return render_to_response('assets/asset_list.html', {'assets': assets}, content_type="text/html")

def asset_detail(request, asset_name):
    asset_detail = get_object_or_404(asset, asset_name=asset_name)
    return render(request, 'assets/asset_detail.html', {'asset_detail': asset_detail})

URLs:

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.asset_list),
    url(r'^detail/(?P<asset_name>.*)/$', views.asset_detail),
)
```

The questionable template:

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Asset Name</th>
    <th>VM Status</th>
    <th>FQDN</th>
    <th>IP Address</th>
    <th>Owner</th>
  </tr>
{% for asset in assets %}  
  <tr>
      <td><a href="{% url assets.views.asset_detail asset_name=asset.asset_name %}">{{ asset.asset_name }}</a></td>
      <td>{{ vmstat }}</td>
      <td>{{ asset.fqdn }}</td>
      <td>{{ asset.ip_address }}</td>
      <td>{{ asset.owner }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

So I've tried tracking down the issue, but apparently I'm missing something about the flow of work here.  Per the error, I see the asset_name trying to be passed and in my urls.py I was pretty open with the regex.  (BTW: The post_detail.html is just an HI! to try to get anything to work).  So I'm a little lost right now and any help would be appreciated.  I'm brand spanking new to Django, so apologies if this is a dumb one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, name your url pattern:

```
url(r'^detail/(?P<asset_name>.*)/$', views.asset_detail, name="asset_detail"),
```

Next, use the name in the url tag. For Django 1.5 and later, wrap the name in quotes.

```
{% url "asset_detail" asset_name=asset.asset_name %}">{{ asset.asset_name }}</a></td>
```